# Python - Geopandas nothing is working

Tags: python, anaconda, geopandas

Hi this is my first post on stack overflow. I am totally new to python, i have some experience with R and .Net but wanting to get into python and try it out. I have installed Anaconda and i have installed my Geopandas package. Running windows and i am running python 3.6 (newest version is best right?)

I want to do an analysis of a spatial data set.

But i am being stopped by just importing my geopandas library.

```
import geopandas as gpd
states = gpd.read_file('states.geojson')
print(states.head())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-564808c3c6e6> in <module>()
----> 1 import geopandas as gpd
      2 states = gpd.read_file('states.geojson')
      3 print(states.head())

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries
      2 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame
      3 
      4 from geopandas.io.file import read_file
      5 from geopandas.io.sql import read_postgis

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py in <module>()
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from pandas import Series
----> 6 import pyproj
      7 from shapely.geometry import shape, Point
      8 from shapely.geometry.base import BaseGeometry

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py in <module>()
    249 #    raise IOError(msg)
    250 
--> 251 set_datapath(pyproj_datadir)
    252 
    253 class Proj(_proj.Proj):

_proj.pyx in _proj.set_datapath (_proj.c:887)()

_proj.pyx in _proj._strencode (_proj.c:3939)()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Similar issue, no answer though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46915852/unicodeencodeerror-whent-trying-to-import-geopandas

Comment: Issue on github: https://github.com/jswhit/pyproj/issues/83

Comment: The problem reported there (and fixed in pyproj, although not yet released it seems) was due to unicode characters in the installation path. However, that doesn't seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it wasn't installed correctly. Through your command prompt try this:

```html
>>> import geopandas
>>> geopandas.__version__
'0.6.1'
```

If you see something different try 'pip install geopandas'